# C - Read from .INI file and pass values to vars

Tags: c, string, file, ini

I'm doing a project for school and I need to read from an .INI file to start my vars for the game. Problem is, I cannot seem to understand how strtok works and I'm really confused at this point.

I know I'm returning an empty struct because I have no idea how to put the specific values into the vars!

Here's my read_from_config.h

```
#ifndef READ_FROM_CONFIG_H
#define READ_FROM_CONFIG_H
#define MAXSTR 500

typedef struct {
  unsigned int xdim;
  unsigned int ydim;
  unsigned int nzombies;
  unsigned int nhumans;
  unsigned int nzplayers;
  unsigned int nhplayers;
  unsigned int turns;
} CONFIG;

CONFIG read_config(char *argv[]);

#endif
```

And here is my read_from_config.c

```
#include "read_from_config.h"
#include "example.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

CONFIG read_config(char *argv[]) {
  char str[MAXSTR];
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  char *filename = argv[1];
  char *token;

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Não foi possível abrir ficheiro de configuração.");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nModo de uso: ./program_name config.ini");
  }

  while (fgets(str, MAXSTR, fp) != NULL) {
      for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++) {
        char *equal = strpbrk (str, "=");
        if (equal) {
          token = strtok(str, "=");
        }
      }
  }
  printf("%d", token[0]);
  CONFIG config;
  return config;
}
```

CONFIG.INI

```
﻿; Dimension of the grid
xdim=20
ydim=20
; Inicial number of zombies and humans
nzombies=20
nhumans=20
; Number of zombies and humans controlled by players
nzplayers=0
nhplayers=1
; Number of maximum turns
maxturns=1000
```

Comment: Is it a compulsion for you to use .ini file? And, do it yourself?

Comment: Beware: you ini file let me thing that the semicolon (`;`) also needs special processing... And you should wonder whether spaces are allowed around keys of values and should be stripped off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `strtok` take a string only the first time it gets called. **All**
subsequent calls must be passed with `NULL`

> *man strtok*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strtok()` function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more nonempty tokens.
>   **On the first call to `strtok()`, the string to be parsed should be specified in `str`.
>   In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str` must be `NULL`.**

Example:

```
char line[] = "a,b,c,d,e,f\n"; // to simulate an fgets line
char *token = strtok(line, ",\n");  // you can add \n to the separator
                                    // to get rid of the \n at the end

puts(token); // prints a
while(token = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
    puts(token);  // prints b then c etc..
```

Keep in mind that `strtok` modifies the source, this is going to fail:

```
strtok("a,b,c", ",");
```

because string literals are not modifiable. In that case you have to make a copy
to a `char[]` or a dynamic allocated `char*`.

If you need to have the source intact after the parsing, then you definitively
need to make a copy.

In your code you do:

```
printf("%d", token[0]);
```

That's not incorrect but perhaps not what you want to do. This line doesn't
print the first character, it prints the ascii value of the first character.

This

```
printf("%c", token[0]);
```

will print the first character.

Also you are doing

```
CONFIG read_config(char *argv[]) {
    ...
    CONFIG config;
    return config;
}
```

You are returning an uninitialized `CONFIG` object, you are ignoring the parsing
and nothing is set in your config object.

Your parsing is also a little bit strange.

```
for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
```

The loop exits immediately because `0 == '\0'`! I don't understand what you are
trying to do with it.

I would first create a helper function to populate the values of the config, see
`set_config_val`. Then you can parse it like this:

```
CONFIG read_config(char *argv[]) {
    ...

    const char *delim = "=\n";
    CONFIG config;

    while (fgets(str, MAXSTR, fp) != NULL) {

        if(strchr(str, '='))
        {
            char varname[100];
            int value;

            token = strtok(line, delim);
            strcpy(varname, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            value = atoi(token);

            set_config_val(&config, varname, value); 
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Skipping line, no = found");
        }

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return config;
}


void set_config_val(CONFIG *config, const char *key, int val)
{
    if(config == NULL)
        return;

    if(strcmp(key, "xdim") == 0)
        config->xdim = val;
    else if(strcmp(key, "ydim") == 0)
        config->ydim = val;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and I finally understand it better.

Comment: @RuiMartins take into consideration the other comments like the one from Serge Ballesta. My parsing is very basic and will break when you have lines that start with `;` or `#`. You should take that into account. Now that you've got a basic code base, you can enhance it. Or you could use a library dedicated to parse ini files. There are lot's of them: https://www.google.com/search?q=C+ini+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b